# Fisher's exact test with opposite direction of categories for two groups

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, fishers-exact-test, frequency

I would like to analyze student performance under two teaching approaches for two classes. We predict that class 1 would outperform class 2 and ideally the performance between two classes should be significantly different, e.g., fewer incompetent students and more full competent students in class 1.

The reason I picked Fisher's exact test is I want to compare frequencies of two groups but my sample size is small; some cells have a count of less than five or even zero. The test is based on a 3 by 2 table below. However, `incompetence` has an opposite desired direction as the other two categories. So my questions are: would the issue of reversed direction of different categories offset the significant difference between two classes when I use this test? Do I need to make any adjustment or refine data? Or any better method I should consider?

```
  categories       class 1  class 2
  Incompetence         2      6       
  Partial competence  18      22
  Full competence     15      10
```